# How to process upto 5K concurrent connection in apache2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2.4

I have set up my server on the digital ocean and it was working very fine. Even if we have a good machine there, still the server was not taking more than 250 to 300 requests.

I checked the apache log and I got the following error there.

```
[Wed Dec 11 01:14:49.586728 2019] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1993] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

I have googled this error and came to know that my apache server has a request limit and I have to increase that. So I put the below configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
      StartServers                     10
      MinSpareServers               10
      MaxSpareServers              20
      ServerLimit                      2000
      MaxRequestWorkers         1500
      MaxConnectionsPerChild    10000
</IfModule>
```

After adding this, I restarted my server and everything is working fine. Now my server is able to handle up to 1000 requests.

I have not deep knowledge in apache but I got ride of trouble. My question is how many requests can be handled by this above configuration. Do I need to change anything for 5K users? usually, we can have up to 5K users at the same time.

We have a good machine on the digital ocean with the following configuration.

```
64 GB Memory
25 GB Disk
Ubuntu 16.04.6 x64
```

Comment: Might be slightly OT but I would recommend horizontally scaling your application, by using load balancers if possible.. spinning up new droplets and removing them as necessary in line with the traffic/demand.

Comment: prefork is the worst possible MPM for scaling

Answer (score 0):

**My question is how many requests can be handled by this above configuration.**

Noone can give you that answer because it depends completely on too many factors - how fast is your application? What size is the droplet? what data center is the droplet in? are you using a database? is that database on the server or external? etc etc

You need to perform load testing to stress test your environment and that will tell you.

Just increasing the max number of *possible* concurrent processes without doing bench marking is a bad idea. It might be able to manage that many processes but it does not mean it will do it efficiently.

**Do I need to change anything for 5K users? usually, we can have up to 5K users at the same time.**

As GBWDev noted with that many users you probably want to scale your environment. Load test your server and find out at what point you get a degraded performance, so for example after 1000 users the request time doubles then you might want to think about adding a load balancer and 3 servers.

I also use digital ocean in this setup and I have found from my own bench marking and scaling experiences that it is far cheaper to scale horizontally with lots of small droplets than it is to scale vertically with one of their mega beast servers.